# Misra C Rule 12.2 - false positive warning?

Tags: c, misra

My CCS 6.1 ARM compiler (for LM3Sxxxx Stellaris) throws a warning :

"MISRA Rule 12.2. The value of an expression shall be the same under any order of evaluation that the standard permits"

for following code:

```
typedef struct {
  ...
  uint32_t bufferCnt;
  uint8_t buffer[100];
  ...
} DIAG_INTERFACE_T;

static DIAG_INTERFACE_T diagInterfaces[1];

...
DIAG_INTERFACE_T * diag = &diagInterfaces[0];
uint8_t data = 0;
diag->bufferCnt = 0;
diag->buffer[diag->bufferCnt++] = data; // line where warning is issued
...
```

I don't see a problem in my code. Is it false positive or my bug?

Comment: I believe it's a very bad idea to use the return value of the increment\decrement operator, no matter what the standart says about the sequence points and so on. It's always better to split that to the separate lines to avoid any ambiguity and to make it more readable to anyone, including yourself or the compiler.

Comment: Analyzers are rarely smart enough to completely eliminate possible aliasing.  Just keep that increment operator in a separate statement and it will stop complaining.

Comment: Well, if I use: `diag->buffer[diag->bufferCnt] = data;
                diag->bufferCnt++;` the warning is still there on the first statement. But I saw the answer below see my comment there.

Comment: Your analyser seems to be really crappy. File a bug report. In this case I think they simply listed the wrong error number. The line is a MISRA violation, but not of rule 12.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you don’t indicate it, this is MISRA-C:2004, Rule 12.2, and is now MISRA-C:2012 Rule 13.2.  As oauh says, this has nothing to do with "order of evaluation”.

I highly recommend referring to MISRA-C:2012 even if you are required to be MISRA-C:2004 compliant, having MISRA-C:2012 around helps, because it has clarified many of the guidelines, including additional rationale, explanations and examples.

You should not be using a compiler to solely check for MISRA-C compliancy, its nice, but compilers #1 goal is not to warn you about all the traps and pitfalls of the language it is dedicated to take advantage of (optimization).  They're not very precise either, as in this case. Also, there are many undefined behaviors across translation units, compilers cannot warn about.  Its best to also use a dedicated MISRA Static analysis tool, one that is not compiler specific, but that warns about all unpredictable constructs from the ISO C standards point of view, not a particular implementation.

As oauh also said, this is a violation of MISRA-C:Rule 12.13, which is now MISRA-C:2012 Rule 13.3 which has been relaxed to permit ++ and -- to be mixed with other operators, provided that the ++ or -- is the only source of side-effects (in your case the assignment is also a side effect in C terminology).

The Rule is not critical, i.e. its well defined behavior, but the different values resulting from the prefix version and the postfix version can cause confusion, thus it is “advisory” meaning no formal deviation is required (again, a decent MISRA-C tool would allow you to suppress this particular violation).

Comment: Thank you I think this is correct answer. I didn't even know there was MISRA 2012. We tried to check for MISRA 98 in IAR and MISRA2004 in CCS - it is library code. Well but I understand this and we will use dedicated tool as you proposed (it was my goal anyway to find some compiler independent solution). I just hope MISRA 2012 does not come with another "surprises" (like warnings at almost each statement) that came when migrating from MISRA 98 to MISRA 2004.

Comment: @tk_ you can get a MISRA-C:2012 pdf for about $40 at misra-c.com - it's a pretty good reference in itself just for c programming (much better than the MISRA-c:2004 document). Unfortunately most of the tools that claim support for MISRA-C are barely adequate  - even some of the expensive ones.

Comment: Thank you for price info. We will definitiely need it and a good independent checker as well.

Answer (score 4):

Put `diag->bufferCnt++` in a separate statement (as it is also advised by [Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) in OP comments) and the warning should not appear.

But regarding MISRA rule 12.2 I see no violation of 12.2 (there is a single sequence point in your statement and no unspecified behavior) in your program and I think it's a bug in your MISRA software.

For information there is also an advisory 12.13 rule in MISRA that says:

> (MISRA-C:2004, 12.13) "The increment (++) and decrement (--) operators should not be mixed with other operators in an expression"

The problem with MISRA is their terminology use is far from perfect, for 12.3, while `->` or `=` are C operators, in the explanation they then seem to talk only about arithmetic operators...

Comment: See my comment above putting the separate statement did not help here. But see below, this is IMO the correct answer. Dedicated compiler independent MISRA checker should be used.

Comment: @tk_ It should be noted that 12.13 is a very good rule to follow, so the ++ should be on a line of its own even if it doesn't please the whining tool.

Comment: @Lundin I don't think so. Personally I prefer this solution. If there are many succesive statements filling up the buffer (with various values) the approach `diag->buffer[diag->bufferCnt++] =` is more readable and code is more compact. If there is only one such statement, then I admit, splitting into two statements does not hurt.

Comment: @tk_ Such code is usually problematic, and also violates MISRA. Better code: `diag->buffer[0] = data1; diag->buffer[1] = data2;` and so on. At the end you write `diag->bufferCnt = absolute_value;`. This allows you to write self-documenting, deterministic code. Wouldn't the reader want to know the exact index where each data item is placed? You can add various static assertions if you worry about the code getting modified during maintenance.

Comment: @Lundin this 12.3 rule also forbids very idiomatic expressions like  `(*s1++ = *s2++)` that are used for ages in `memcpy` or `strcpy` implementations.

Comment: @ouah Yes, which is good, since as we can tell from SO, not a single beginner manages to read and understand that line. If it wasn't such a common line, I would have problems understanding it too. You can rewrite that line in clearer ways which results in 100% equivalent machine code.

Comment: @ouah For example strcpy can be implemented as `*s1 = *s2;  while(*s2 != '\0')
  {
    s1++;
    s2++;
    *s1 = *s2;
  }`

Comment: @Lundin This approach (absolute indexing) was present in the library code originally. But was too problematic for maintenance as the library grew. You would have to see the entire code for further discussion. Of course, a function would be clean solution here but with every function stack size grows etc. (the library is targeted for very constrained environments as well). Note that we don't use inline functions or compiler optimizations doing that (often errorneously).

Comment: @tk_ right, that is why this rule is advisory, the compiler behavior for your code is well defined, the concern is for comprehension as Lundin says, but if this is idiomatic in legacy code, it could be less understandable by the experts who are familiar with and maintain the code.  Don't blindly follow or ignore MISRA-C warnings, in this case you are not required to to formally document and get approval why you turned off this warning, however you should describe the comments of your reasoning you just gave to Lundin (just in case he has to maintain your code someday ;-)

Comment: @Veriloud That was we've done - documented the reasons why we turned off particular warnings. The same for splint. Just have learned recently that some checkers might be quite buggy, which is obviously the case of TI's CCS 6.1. I'll place bug reports on TI site later.